# How to get Attributes in StringTemplate v4

Tags: java, stringtemplate-4

I have following code

```
String templateString = "Some Text $attribute1$ more text $attribute2$ more text"; 
ST stringTemplate = new ST(templateString ,'$','$');`
```

How can I iterate over all attributes i.e. attribute1, attribute2 etc?
I want to get all list of attributes in template.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a valid `ST`? Can you use it?

Comment: Yes, it is valid ST. I can use add(), to replace attribute value, but unable to get the attributes list.

Answer (score 0):

In groovy was using just a regex like this and it seems to do what I need for now

```
   List<String> extractTemplateVariables( String statement ) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( /\$(\w*)\$/ );
    def List<String> runTimeParms = []
    def matcher = pattern.matcher( statement )

    while (matcher.find()) {
        runTimeParms << matcher.group( 1 )

    }
    runTimeParms.removeAll( Collections.singleton( null ) );
    runTimeParms.unique( false )
```

}

But I've been told the proper way is to examine the ast something like this:

```
   final int ID = 25
    char delimiter = '$'
    ST st = new org.stringtemplate.v4.ST( statement, delimiter, delimiter );

    def dataFieldNames = []
    def t = st.getAttributes(  )
    st.impl.ast.getChildren().each {

        if (it != null) {
            CommonTree child = it as CommonTree
            if (child.toString().equals( "EXPR" )) {
                if (child.getChildCount() == 1) {
                    CommonTree expressionChild = child.getChild( 0 )
                    if (expressionChild.getToken().getType() == ID) {
                        dataFieldNames.add( expressionChild.toString() )
                    } else if (expressionChild.toString().equals( "PROP" )) {
                        if (expressionChild.getChildCount() == 2) {
                            dataFieldNames.add(
                                    expressionChild.getChild( 0 ).toString() +
                                            "." +
                                            expressionChild.getChild( 1 ).toString() )
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    dataFieldNames.unique( false )

}
```

but I don't understand the structure or what I'm doing here, and it's not seeing any more than the first one. Maybe someone can help us figure out what the best way to do it would be